# How do I look at column metadata in Sybase?

Tags: metadata, sybase, sap-ase

I have a list of columns a co-worker has given to me, but these columns reside in different tables in the DB. Is there some kind of tool in Sybase where I can query the table a column belongs to?

(I've tried Google-ing for this kind of tool, but no luck so far)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

syscolumns holds column metadata.

select * from syscolumns where name = ;

The id column in syscolumns is the id of the column's table, in sysobjects;

```
select b.name as tablename, a.name as columnname
from syscolumns a join systables b on (a.id = b.id) 
where b.type='U' and b.name = 'foo';
```

gets all columns for the table named 'foo'. The type = 'U' limits it to user tables.

```
select b.name as tablename, a.name as columnname
from syscolumns a join systables b on (a.id = b.id) 
where b.type='U' and a.name = 'foo';
```

gets all columns named 'foo'.

Most current version of ASE will use `sysbojects` instead of `systables`

Comment: Thanks! Yes this actually helps. I also found a diagram of Sybase ASE that visualizes your answer: 
http://download.sybase.com/pdfdocs/asg1250e/poster.pdf

Comment: In later version of Sybase one needs to use sysobjects instead of systables

Comment: i tried select * from syscolumns and none of the columns of my tables show up

Comment: if you know the table name already sp_help tableName will give table details including column names.

Answer (score 3):

I had to make a few small change for it to work:

```
select  b.name as tablename, 
        a.name as columnname
from    dbo.syscolumns a 
join    sysobjects     b on a.id = b.id
where   b.type='U' 
and     upper(a.name) like '%FOO%'      -- wildcard search for column name
and     b.name = 'bar'                  -- exclude tables
order by b.name
```

Comment: I guess you meant b.name != 'bar'

Answer (score 0):

You can find the information for any column in:

```sql
SELECT * 
  FROM sys.syscolumns
```

If you want to know to what table a column belongs:

```sql
SELECT cname, tname 
  FROM sys.syscolumns
 WHERE tname IN ('col_1', 'col_2')
```

<sup>NOTE: I test this in Sybase ASA 9.</sup>