# PHP: PDO + CSV export not downloading (headers issue?)

Tags: php, export-to-csv

I'm having a hard time making my CSV export function work.
I've found around plenty of examples using mysqli_* functions, but I'm actually using PDOs so I had to adapt some questions/answers to my needs.
From what I can see, I'm properly parsing and writing data to the *.csv file, but at the end I don't simply get any "Download" modal from the browser.
Again, looking around, I've understood I may have some kind of problem with my headers, so I'm asking for your help.

This is my PHP function snippet:

```
function downloadAsCSV($dsn, $dbUser, $dbPsw, $options) {
    // New PDO connection.
    $pdo = pdoConnect($dsn, $dbUser, $dbPsw, $options);

    $query = ... // Not going to write it down.

    // Let's query the database, ...
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);

    // Setting up the query variables here...
    [...]
    // Executing the statement...
    $stmt->execute();

    // Headers.
    header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header("Content-Type: text/csv");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='export.csv'");
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
    header("Expires: 0");

    // Let's open tbe "*.csv" file where we'll save the results.
    $fp = fopen("php://output", "w");

    if ($fp) {
        $first_row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $headers = array_keys($first_row);
        fputcsv($fp, array_values($first_row));
        fputcsv($fp, $headers);

        // ... fetch the results...
        $workpiecesArray = $stmt->fetchAll();

        // ... and, finally, export them.
        foreach ($workpiecesArray as $workpiece) {
            fputcsv($fp, array_values($workpiece));
        }
    }

    fclose($fp);

    // Closing the connection.
    $stmt = null;
    $pdo = null;
}

function mysqli_field_name($result, $field_offset) {
    $properties = mysqli_fetch_field_direct($result, $field_offset);

    return is_object($properties) ? $properties->name : null;
}
```

I've taken inspiration to write the table column titles from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29762660/4938112).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need to do is to print the file, which you're not doing right now.
See this example using readfile:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php#example-5554

Simply put:

1.Replace

```
$fp = fopen("php://output", "w");
```

with

```
$tmpfname = tempnam("/", "");
$fp = fopen($tmpfname, "w");
```

2.Replace

```
fclose($fp);
```

with

```
fclose($fp);
readfile($tmpfname);
unlink($tmpfname);
```

and this will work

Comment: I'm not reading a file, but getting the data from a MySQL DB using PDOs. I'm sorry, but I probably didn't get what you were meaning.

Comment: @Davide3i see my updated answer with step-by-step on what to do with your code

Comment: Hi, thanks. Unfortunately it still not works. The only unusual thing I'm seeing is that the file pointer is like this: "resource id='6' type='stream'".

Comment: please recheck the variable names, I checked the code locally and it does exactly what you described

Comment: For what I can see, my *.tmp file is being created (containing the data got from the DB), but at the end it just get deleted and I can't obtain any *.csv file: it should put it in the same directory, right?

Comment: If you need the CSV saved on disk, simply remove unlink from the code. that takes care of file removal.
if you need the file to be saved in somewhere else than /tmp, you can modify `$tmpfname = tempnam("/", "");` and use something like `$tmpfname = "/my/absolute/path/to/file.csv";`

Comment: I don't really know why, but the *.tmp file gets correctly created, but even after removing `unlink($tmpName);`, I can't simply get any *.csv file (the browser is not prompting me to download it) and the *.tmp file disappears. I can't get what I'm doing wrong. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171465/discussion-between-janmyszkier-and-davide3i).

Answer (score 1):

```
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="export.csv"');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize('export.csv'));
readfile($csvFile);
exit;
`put this after` fclose($fp);
```

Comment: Not working, I'm sorry. I'm still having a blank page.

Comment: any error you are getting.
Add error_reporting(-1);  at the top of your code

Comment: No, any error. Using Xdebug I can I'm saving data to the $fp, but in the end I am not input with the download file request.