# How to see Table columns in sorted order in Sybase

Tags: sql, database, sybase, sap-ase

sp_help lists the table columns but they are not sorted as per their names (perhaps as per the actual order in which they are present in table i guess). For many columns in a table it gets difficult to find a column name , so is there any way i can see column names sorted by their names.

Comment: Is information schema supported? select table_name, column_name from information_schema.columns order by table_name, column_name?

Comment: try `select col.name
from sysobjects tab
inner join syscolumns col
on tab.id = col.id
where tab.type = 'U'
and tab.name = 'TABLE_NAME' order by col.name`

Comment: Thanks @Sachu ..the query works ! .. and not sure about information_schema ..

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I look at column metadata in Sybase?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/723115/how-do-i-look-at-column-metadata-in-sybase)

Comment: @user1107108 posted as answer :)..what u not sure abt information schema

Comment: @MichaelGardner its not duplicate ..there, query uses systables (which i cant find in my db atleast) here it uses sysobjects which works for me ..

Comment: You'll notice in the comments that newer versions of ASE use sysbojects instead of systables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select col.name from 
sysobjects tab 
inner join 
syscolumns col 
on tab.id = col.id 
where tab.type = 'U' 
and tab.name = 'TABLE_NAME' 
order by col.name
```